# instalar proyecto laravel en CWpanel

Tags: laravel-5, servidor, hosting

mi siguiente consulta es por que trato de instalar un proyecto laravel ya creado, y no he tenido suerte. el servidor es de varios dominios en el cual esta de esta manera

```
/home/nombredominio/
```

explico, primero subi el proyecto y coloque en `public_html` la carpeta `public` y el resto de las carpetas en otra carpeta `xxxxxxx` quedando de esta manera

```
/home/nombredominio/public_html   <<------- carpeta public

/home/nombredominio/xxxxxxxxx     <<------resto de carpetas
```

luego me dirijo a `/public_html/index.php`

y renombro las lineas

```
require __DIR__.'/xxxxxxx/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/xxxxxxxx/bootstrap/app.php';
```

(ACA EN ESTA EXPLICACION CAPAZ NO COLOQUE EXACTAMENTE COMO DEBERIA SER YA QUE ANDO EN PRUEBAS Y BORRE. MAS SE QUE LLEGABA A LA RUTA YA QUE ANTES ME DABA EL ERROR DE RUTAS Y LUEGO LO RESOLVI)... SALTANDO AL ERROR QUE COMENTARE ABAJO

Luego al dar `www.xxxxxxx.com`

me sale este error

> /framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php'(include_path='.:/opt/alt/php72/usr/lib/php')

Estuve leyendo y SE DICE que era la version de PHP, pero el servidor esta en 7.2.5 y mi version de laravel es 5.6

Primera vez que ando subiendo laravel a un servidor. disculpen las novatadas.

Comment: Bueno lo que vi que me funciono es  usar el comando chown -R xxxxx:xxxxx/

Answer (score 0):

Prueba colocando las rutas de esta manera

```
require __DIR__.'/../xxxxxxx/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../xxxxxxxx/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Espero te funcione.